# Elasticsearch rellocation shard stucks

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I'm delete node from my cluster using this command

```
curl -u elastig:themoststrongpasswordever -XPUT 10.0.10.10:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{

"transient" :{

  "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.240.235"

}

}'
```

but the some index does not allocate for about 40+ Hours

```
prod-tajikistan-2021.06.17 0 p RELOCATING 1176481284 626.6gb 10.0.240.235 elastic-12 -> 10.0.10.10 PUoA_SbUQm2KYeJTzucxxg
```

can i force cancel this allocation?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_yes_decisions=true&include_disk_info=true` ?

Comment: just big array with indexes

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to see that big array